# How to parse USPTO XML files with Ruby and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

It's been the whole day that I'm trying to figure out how to parse [USPTO bulk XML files](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html). I've tried to download [one](http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2014/ipg140513.zip) of those files, unzipped it and then run:

```
Nokogiri::XML(File.open('ipg140513.xml'))
```

But it seems to load only the first element, not all patents (in that file there are few thousands)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the file contains thousands of records, it might be better/smarter/safer to write a SAX parser (using Nokogiri of course). By default, Nokogiri uses a DOM parser, which means the entire XML document is loaded into memory before parsing occurs, which can cripple a machine if the XML is big enough.

Answer (score 3):

The file you linked to, and presumably the others, are not valid XML because they do not have a root element. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element):

> Each XML document has exactly one single **root element**.

Nokogiri hints at this if you look at the errors (suggested by [Arup Rakshit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701293/how-to-parse-uspto-xml-files-with-ruby-and-nokogiri#comment36422291_23701978)), as detailed in [the documentation](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html):

```
Nokogiri::XML(File.open("/Users/b/Downloads/ipg140513.xml")).errors # =>
# [
#   #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>,
#   #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>
# ]
```

The file appears to be a concatenation of a series of valid XML files, each having a `<us-patent-grant/>` as its root element.

Fortunately, Nokogiri can handle this invalid XML if you process it as a document fragment. Try this:

```
Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(File.read('ipg140513.xml')).select{|element| element.name == 'us-patent-grant'}
```

The `select` chooses the root node of each concatenated document, ignoring the processing instructions and DTD declarations.

Alternately, you could pre-process the file and split it into its constituent, correctly-formatted documents. Parsing a 650MB document all at once is quite slow and memory intensive.

Comment: Your answer is good, but *Nokogiri* itself can tell, what error it is experiencing. Look this - http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html

Comment: Thank you Buck! Yeah, I've tried with the DocumentFragment and my laptop just died. Now I'm trying to figure out how to split the xml in multiple files, considering also that I don't need all patents in it, but just few of them. I also searched if USPTO provides xml files for single patents but I cannot find anything, just the bulk zips